# URL redirect plugin regex input for match and target

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm panicking a little, so sorry if I haven't explained well enough.

1. I've dealt with quite the nightmare of a permalink restructuring experience
2. Old permalink= sitename/archives/postid
3. desired new= sitename/postname

tried everything it seems. I've even dabbled with /?p=$1 (<-----that nonsense!). But now i'm getting some crazy error when i go to my old permalink structure that reads:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 0.0.37.89
>   Suggestions:
>   Try reloading: 0.­0.­37.­89

and this was supposed to be "redirected".
I give up. please help.

sitename= brightontheday.com

Comment: Are you doing this redirection using `.htaccess`?  If yes, please post this file if you can.

Comment: no, via the redirection plugin. I would attach a screen shot but my work firewall/server blocks all pastebin/dropbox/etc. sites! @HeatfanJohn

Comment: @HeatfanJohn should i just bite the frickin bullet and do it via .htaccess?

Comment: Are you able to add an image using Stackoverflow Image button adding a picture from your computer?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn i ended up figuring it out! I didn't know that in order to use the $1/$2 /$3, I had to first define the parameters with ()()() if that makes sense. And once I figured that out, I was able to direct the url's. I did a crappy job explaining that...but basically, there was quite the steep learning curve with regex!

Comment: Great to hear, you should post your solution when you are able.

Comment: Hi. This question appears in the 'unanswered' list but it seems that your problem was solved by comments. Would you mind answering your own question with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I used the redirection plugin to redirect all old URL permalinks (/archives/postID) to the new permalink (/postID/postname)

also, the issue appeared to be due to cashing via cloudfare. It's important to to note that one should put cloudfare in "developer mode" while making site wide changes.